# How to properly use \Join while specifying column name?

Tags: math-mode, join

I have to data views that I want to write that they are joined on a specific attribute, what I do is:

```
\emph{view1} \begin{small}$\Join_{attribute}$\end{small} \emph{view2}
```

But attribute takes much space after the join sign and is written very small so that it could not be read, which I don't like, any idea how to achieve this with a better way?

Comment: As always on this site, you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is without having to add any code. Your example needs code added in order to even compile it.

Comment: why small? it will be be very hard to read, also words should not be in math italic: `\emph{view1}  $\Join_{\mathrm{attribute}}$`

Comment: small or normal size didn't change anything

Comment: small will be smaller unless you have a very non-standard  font setup, but as you have provided no example it is impossible  to debug for you.